# react native image cache never expires changing etag image on S3 for the same uri

Tags: amazon-s3, react-native

I want to cache invalidate on the react native. In my application, when user image was changed, image cache is not expiring. Image's etag is changing on the same URI. Then I am reloading my application, but user image is not changing.

I know this workaround:
`<Image source={{uri:'${imageUrl}${random number or anything else}'}}`

react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.5
node: 6.11.2
npm: 5.5.1
platform: Android
OS: Ubuntu 16.04