# React Native Images On Android Never Reload When Uri Doesn't Change

Tags: android, image, react-native

Despite uploading a new image to an s3 hosted url, the `<Image>` component will not update the image if the uri does not change. This is a problem for Android only as far as I can tell, because for iOS you can use the `cache: 'reload'` prop.

I have resorted to [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12606#issuecomment-363397371) solution:

```
<Image 
  source={uri: imageUrlFromS3 + '?time=' + new Date(), cache: 'reload'}
  style={width: 100, height: 100}
/>
```

By adding a meaningless query to the url, the component recognizes that the uri has changed, which then refreshes the updated image. Similarly, I have tried this by changing the key to be a new Date(). This seems like horrible for performance, due to the aggressive rerendering.

It seems that [this has been a problem for a long time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47595255/13315676).

I have seen [some answers that require using another package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54366063/13315676).

Is there another solution to this problem that doesn't require using another package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of concatenating the current Date prop, what you can do is create a state that takes the value of a random number whether you execute the query (the one that updates the image) and concatenate that to the uri, like this:

```
// state to notify the updating image process
const [onUpdateImage, setOnUpdateImage] = useState(Math.random())

// Function that updates the image
const updateImageQuery = () => {
  ...
  setOnUpdateImage(Math.random())
}

//Image Display:
<Image style={{ width: 133, height: 133, }}
     source={{
        uri: image_URL + "?" + onUpdateImage               
       }}
 />
```

This way you can optimize the App performance and do the image re-rendering only when it's necessary.
If the image is exposed in other screens, you can create onUpdateImage as a Context and use it globally.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do it like this:

```
source={uri: imageUrlFromS3 + '?' + new Date()}
```

Comment: Not accepting this answer because it is a variation of my solution in the initial question. Whether I use "?" or "?time=" is not a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can substring the unix timestamp such that it could re-render every N milliseconds.

For example, `source={uri: imageUrlFromS3 + '?' + Date.now().toString().substring(0,10) + "000" ...`

would mean it would re-render every 1000 milliseconds = 1 second.